# Need assistance with a Base85 (Ascii85) Encoder

Tags: java, math, base85

### Base85 ASCII Encoder/Decoder

LOOK HERE FOR INTIAL REFERENCE ->> [Base85 Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)

I am making a Base85 encoder/decoder for java, I don't want the answer or solution to my programming or code from a complete encoder. I can provide sources from my code, but it is unnecessary, as this question is more geared to understand the concept. I included all the steps outlined on that wikipedia page in my code successfully up to the 32-bit Value point, where the total value of the 32bit in base 10 is converted to base85.

LOOK HERE ->> [Base85 Encoding Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEp4i.png)

So, to be specific, I have successfully gotten the number 1298230816 - but now I'm stumped. How do I get the numbers represented in base 85 as shown above? (**24***85^4; **73***85^3; **80***85^2; **78***85; **61**). What mathematical process would I go about to find those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, but I'm guessing that you want to know how to *compute* `a, b, c, d, e` such that `N = a * 85^4 + b * 85^3 + c * 85^2 + d * 85 + e`.

The answer is:

1. Take N remainder `85` to give you `e`.
2. Divide N by `85`.
3. Repeat for `d`, `c` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. I figured it out almost as soon as your began using remainders.